# how to detect that user internet connection is on?

Tags: asp.net

I have a web page(ASP.NET) that a client (just one) connect to it and after registration I save it's IP address into a text file. 
What I want to do is if this client has closed the web page, I want to detect it and clear my text file .

Comment: You will probably have to ping that client.

Comment: can you explain how can I Ping in asp.net every (for example ) 5 minutes . thanks.

Comment: In an intranet environment, this may be possible. On the wider internet, this isn't doable (due to e.g. dynamic proxies, every request for one user may appear to come from a different IP address). What's your particular situation?

Comment: [Check user internet connectivity using Asp.Net C#](http://shawpnendu.blogspot.co.uk/2010/02/check-user-internet-connectivity-using.html)

Comment: I want to Upload a site on Internet that this page is a page of this website .

Comment: You can simply use Ajax notifications from client side to indicate that client is alive. In more advanced scenarios you can take advantage of HTML5 Web Sockets, or alternative technologies to simulate "push" functionality in older browsers

Comment: As I said, on the Internet, there's no guarantee of a 1-1 mapping of IP addresses to users (multiple users can exist behind a single IP address, a single user may use multiple IP addresses). Tell us the problem to solve, not how you thought you would solve it.

Comment: With what code can I check if my connection in C# to Oracle is open? I want a message to display if the connection is open or close.I use web based application with oracle connection
 
I got error "Operator '==' cannot be applied to operands of type 'System.Data.ConnectionState' and 'method group"

Answer (score 1):

Using this You can check Connection

**System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable()**

***EXAMPLE:--***

```
public static void **testInternetConnection**()
{
    if (System.Net.NetworkInformation.NetworkInterface.GetIsNetworkAvailable())
    {      
      System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("This computer is connected to the internet");
    }
     else
    {
     System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("This computer is not connected to the internet");
    }  
}
```

Comment: This checks connection locally, not clients on a web site.